# In selenium , how to enable/disable webrtc arguments for safari browser

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, safari

Trying to disable/enable mock capture devcies through selenium for safari browser

````
let driver = await new Builder().withCapabalities({ 'webkit:WebRTC': {
              DisableInsecureMediaCapture: true,
              DisableMockDeviceCapture: true,
            }}).forBrowser('safari')  
     
    .build();  
    ```
````